Help me understand numbers from "Balance and Performance Activity" chart of Fidelity
I think I am clear on what these numbers are but want to validate my understanding with community.

As per the above chart,

I deposited total of $439,161.33 into my account from Feb 01 2021 to
Oct 08 2024
I earned dividends & interest of total $15,041.25 from
Feb 01 2021 to Oct 08 2024
My final balance is $525,696.71
That means, my net gain including dividends & interest is $86,535.38 for
an investment of $439,161.33 (which translates to 19.70% gain)

Did I get this right?


That means, my net gain including dividends & interest is $86,535.38 for an investment of $439,161.33 (which translates to 19.70% gain)

Yes and no - it's true your earnings are 19.7% of your total net invested amount, but since you had different balances over time (due to adding/removing funds at different times), your current balance is not the same as if you had deposited the entire amount at the beginning and did not withdraw anything.  It also does not reflect the average performance of your investments over that time period.
Most of your balance was deposited in 2023, so your overall rate of return is "skewed" (or over-weighted) by the performance of your investments since that period.
It may not make a difference in your planning if you're (correctly) focused on how much you have now, but it can be confusing to see a "personal rate of return" and compare it to, say, the S&P 500 over that same time period. It may be better or worse depending on the timing on inflows and outflows, not just your investment choices.
If you want a few different measures that might be more meaningful, do some research on Time-weighted return and Money-weighted return (essentially IRR). You can also find answers on this site that explain them {caveat: some of those answers are mine, which means that they're awesome ;-) }
